# Is there a ריבית problem with inviting a friend for a meal by saying "I owe you a meal invitation, so please come over to eat by me today"?

Tags: halacha, lending-interest-ribbis

The רמ"א  in  שולחן ערוך אור"ח סימן קע סעף יג says:
לא יאמר אדם לחבירו בא ואכול עמי מה שהאכלתני דהוי כפורע לו חובו ונראה כאלו הלוה לו ויש לחוש שיאכילהו יותר ואית ביה משום רבית:

One should not say to his friend "Come and eat with me what you have given me to eat", for it is like he is paying him his debt, and it looks as if he lent him (something), and we are concerned that he will feed him more (than that which he had eaten from his friend), and this constitutes ribbis.

Question: Is there a ריבית problem with inviting a friend for a meal by saying "**I owe you a meal invitation**, so please come over to eat by me today" ?

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna Berura ([170:31](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.170.31?with=all&lang=bi)) says that it's not actual ribbis but it's similar to ribbis, because he did not have that in mind when feeding him.

> משום רבית - כלומר דמחזי כריבית אבל מדינא לאו ריבית הוא דלא היה מתכוין בשעה שהאכילו בראשונה לכך

So It's not a problem of actual ribbis, but one is not allowed to do it as it looks like ribbis. as the Shulchan Aruch says in OC [170:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.170.13?with=all&lang=bi) as stated in the question.